# Is fuchsia supports 32 bit ARM architecture?

Tags: 32-bit, architecture

Is fuchsia supports 32 bit ARM architecture?

If yes, how to build for 32-bit architecture ?

Comment: You already asked this here https://www.reddit.com/r/Fuchsia/comments/g1n4gr/is_fuchsia_supports_32bit_architecture/fngnhs2/ and got the answer...

Comment: Your first question is answerable, your second is far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. It only supports 64 bit ARMv8 or 64 bit x86-64 processors.

See: https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/refs/heads/master/README.md